# How to create blue verification mark in flutter

Tags: flutter

I would like to give verification mark to my users. Pretty much something like what Instagram or Facebook has

something like this

[image]

how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `svg` or `icon` in your project as,

```
 IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.verified),
            color: Colors.yellow,
            highlightColor: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: _onSearchButtonPressed(),
          ),
```

implementation:

```
static const IconData verified = IconData(0xe699, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons');
```

checkout these also for more info:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons/verified-constant.html

https://www.svgrepo.com/vectors/verified/

Comment: Thank you for your help!.. I am using firestore right now. Say, I store firestore field (isVerified) as boolean, I have to write "if" statement to display the verification badge, right? Like if isVerified = true, then show the badge or else don't show the badge. Could you please show me know to use if state in this scenario ? my apology if I am making you confused.

Comment: I cannot change the `tick` color inside the verified badge, I can only specify one color ` Icon(
                                        Icons.verified,
                                        color: AppColors.Secondary,
                                        size: 30,
                                      ),`